# REP-52266: The in-process Reports Server rep_daniyal_tariq failed to start.oracle.reports.RWException

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oraclereports

My Oracle Reports server 10g wasn't working properly while interacting through Oracle Forms 10g with following error:

> REP-52266: The in-process Reports Server rep_user failed to start.oracle.reports.RWException: IDL:oracle/reports/RWException:1.0

Then I got to know about below solution from stack-overflow

1. Search the file rwnetwork.conf
2. Change the lines

**From**

```
<multicast channel="228.5.6.7" port="14021" timeout="1000" retry="5"/>
<!--namingService name="Cos" host="127.0.0.1" port="14021"/-->
```

**To**

```
<!--multicast channel="228.5.6.7" port="14021" timeout="1000" retry="5"/-->
<namingService name="Cos" host="127.0.0.1" port="14021"/>
```

3. Start the`namingservice : namingservice 14021`

After trying all three steps successfully now I am in trouble with following error:

> REP-52266: The in-process Reports Server rep_user failed to start.oracle.reports.RWException:
>   IDL:oracle/reports/RWException:1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution for

> REP-52266: The in-process Reports Server rep_user failed to
>   start.oracle.reports.RWException: IDL:oracle/reports/RWException:1.0

1. simply restart you Server and make sure your OC4J is not start yet
   (if you have your OC4J on startup then first stop that then restart
   your server)
2. now before you open any thing go to 
   C:\DevSuiteHome_1\reports\server\
3. Now delete the file placed here "your_server_name.DAT" File
4. After this now start your services of OC4J and run the Report

Hope it will work for you too
Thanks!
Daniyal Tariq